# How to make a div stick to the bottom of a page with no wrapper?

Tags: html, css

So I'm in the process of building my website, this is all I have in my body tag:

```css
   #social-media {
     width: 175px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding-top: 10%;
    }
    #social-media img {
     padding: 5px;
    }
    #social-media ul li {
     display: inline;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="search">
      <form action="search.php" method="get">
      <input name="keywords" type="text" placeholder="Search for a movie!" autocomplete="off" size="40">
        <input type="submit" value="DRINK!">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="social-media"> 
    <img src="facebook2.png">
    <img src="twitter2.png">
    </div>
```

I'm trying to pin the social-media div to the bottom of the page no matter what device the user is viewing on, is it possible to do this with no wrapper?

Comment: You already have a wrapping element – so why not just use that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to always appear at the bottom of the screen then use

```
#social-media {
    positioning: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The documentation on W3Schools can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

If you want to ensure that it is always at the bottom of the actual page (below other content) then try:

```
#social-media {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need the div to be "absolutely" positioned at the bottom, like this:

```css
#social-media {
    width: 175px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#social-media img {
    padding: 5px;
}
#social-media ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="logo"></div>
<div class="search">
  <form action="search.php" method="get">
  <input name="keywords" type="text" placeholder="Search for a movie!" autocomplete="off" size="40">
    <input type="submit" value="DRINK!">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="social-media"> 
<img src="facebook2.png">
<img src="twitter2.png">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: when I do this, it overlaps the the div I have on my search results page, any ideas?